# C program that reads all characters from an input file

Tags: c

Am supposed to write a C program that reads all characters from an input file named: a.txt and counts and prints how many occurrences of each character are in the file.
Ignore the character space and the character tab.

Am not getting any error but there is completely nothing being output. Where did I go wrong?

For example for the below text file;

For Q2: I cant format.
I don't know if these problems
Will affect. The grade

```
The output is:
        There are 1 of character: 2
        There are 1 of character: :
        There are 1 of character: F
        There are 2 of character: I
        There are 1 of character: Q
        There are 1 of character: T
        There are 1 of character: W
        There are 4 of character: a
        There are 1 of character: b
        There are 2 of character: c
        There are 2 of character: d
        There are 6 of character: e
        There are 4 of character: f
        There are 1 of character: g
        There are 2 of character: h
        There are 2 of character: i
        There are 1 of character: k
        There are 3 of character: l
        There are 2 of character: m
        There are 3 of character: n
        There are 5 of character: o
        There are 1 of character: p
        There are 4 of character: r
        There are 2 of character: s
        There are 5 of character: t
        There are 1 of character: w
```

```
        #include<stdio.h>
        #include<stdlib.h>



        int main()
        {
            FILE *fp;

            fp = fopen("a.txt", "r+"); //a.txt



            int array[127] = { 0 };

            char filechar;

            while (fscanf(fp,"%d",&filechar))


            {
                array[(int)(filechar)]++;// Increment
            }

            for ( int i = 33; i <= 64; i++)
            {

                switch (i) {
                case 33:
                    if (array[i] > 0)
                        printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , '!' );
                    break;
                case 34:
                    if (array[i] > 0)
                    printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , '"' );

                    break;
                case 35:
                    if (array[i] > 0)
                    printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , '#' );

                    break;
                case 36:
                    if (array[i] > 0)
                    printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , '$' );

                    break;
                case 37:
                    if (array[i] > 0)
                    printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , '%' );

                    break;
                case 38:
                    if (array[i] > 0)
                    printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , '&' );

                    break;
                case 39:
                    if (array[i] > 0)
                    printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , '!' );

                    break;
                case 40:
                    if (array[i] > 0)
                    printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , ')' );

                    break;
                case 41:
                    if (array[i] > 0)
                    printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , '()' );

                    break;
                case 42:
                    if (array[i] > 0)
                    printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , '*' );

                    break;
                case 43:
                    if (array[i] > 0)
                    printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , '+' );

                    break;
                case 44:
                    if (array[i] > 0)
                    printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , ',' );

                    break;
                case 45:
                    if (array[i] > 0)
                    printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , '-' );

                    break;
                case 46:
                    if (array[i] > 0)
                    printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , '.' );

                    break;
                case 47:
                    if (array[i] > 0)
                    printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , '/' );

                    break;
                case 48:
                    if (array[i] > 0)
                    printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , '0' );

                    break;
                case 49:
                    if (array[i] > 0)
                    printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , '1' );

                    break;
                case 50:
                    if (array[i] > 0)
                    printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , '2' );

                    break;
                case 51:
                    if (array[i] > 0)
                    printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , '3' );

                    break;
                case 52:
                    if (array[i] > 0)
                    printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , '4' );

                    break;
                case 53:
                    if (array[i] > 0)
                    printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , '5' );

                    break;
                case 54:
                    if (array[i] > 0)
                    printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , '6' );

                    break;
                case 55:
                    if (array[i] > 0)
                    printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , '7' );

                    break;
                case 56:
                    if (array[i] > 0)
                    printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , '8' );

                    break;
                case 57:
                    if (array[i] > 0)
                    printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , '9' );

                    break;
                case 58:
                    if (array[i] > 0)
                    printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , ':' );

                    break;
                case 59:
                    if (array[i] > 0)
                    printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , ';' );

                    break;
                case 60:
                    if (array[i] > 0)
                    printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , '<' );

                    break;
                case 61:
                    if (array[i] > 0)
                    printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , '=' );

                    break;
                case 62:
                    if (array[i] > 0)
                    printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , '>' );

                    break;
                case 63:
                    if (array[i] > 0)
                    printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , '?' );

                    break;
                case 64:
                    if (array[i] > 0)
                    printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , '@' );

                    break;


                }
            }



            for (int i = 65; i <= 90; i++)
            {

                switch (i) {
                case 65:
                        if (array[i] >0)
                        printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , 'A' );

                            break;
                case 66:
                        if (array[i] > 0)
                        printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , 'B' );

                    break;
                case 67:
                        if (array[i] > 0)
                        printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , 'C' );

                    break;
                case 68:
                        if (array[i] > 0)
                        printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , 'D' );

                    break;
                case 69:
                        if (array[i] > 0)
                        printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , 'E' );

                    break;
                case 70:
                        if (array[i] > 0)
                        printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , 'F' );

                    break;
                case 71:
                        if (array[i] > 0)
                        printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , 'G' );

                    break;
                case 72:
                        if (array[i] > 0)
                        printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , 'H' );

                    break;
                case 73:
                        if (array[i] > 0)
                        printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , 'I' );

                    break;
                case 74:
                        if (array[i] > 0)
                        printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , 'J' );

                    break;
                case 75:
                        if (array[i] > 0)
                        printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , 'K' );

                    break;
                case 76:
                        if (array[i] > 0)
                        printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , 'L' );

                    break;
                case 77:
                        if (array[i] > 0)
                        printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , 'M' );

                    break;
                case 78:
                        if (array[i] > 0)
                        printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , 'N' );

                    break;
                case 79:
                        if (array[i] > 0)
                        printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , 'O' );

                    break;
                case 80:
                        if (array[i] > 0)
                        printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , 'P' );

                    break;
                case 81:
                        if (array[i] > 0)
                        printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , 'Q' );

                    break;
                case 82:
                        if (array[i] > 0)
                        printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , 'R' );

                    break;
                case 83:
                        if (array[i] > 0)
                        printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , 'S' );

                    break;
                case 84:
                        if (array[i] > 0)
                        printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , 'T' );

                    break;
                case 85:
                        if (array[i] > 0)
                        printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , 'U' );

                    break;
                case 86:
                        if (array[i] > 0)
                        printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , 'V' );

                    break;
                case 87:
                        if (array[i] > 0)
                        printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , 'W' );

                    break;
                case 88:
                        if (array[i] > 0)
                        printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , 'X' );

                    break;
                case 89:
                        if (array[i] > 0)
                        printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , 'Y' );

                    break;
                case 90:
                        if (array[i] > 0)
                        printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , 'Z' );

                    break;
                }
            }


            for (int i = 97; i <= 122; i++)
            {
                switch (i) {
                case 97:
                        if (array[i] > 0)
                        printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , 'a' );

                    break;
                case 98:
                        if (array[i] > 0)
                        printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , 'b' );

                    break;
                case 99:
                        if (array[i] > 0)
                        printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , 'c' );

                    break;
                case 100:
                        if (array[i] > 0)
                        printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , 'd' );

                    break;
                case 101:
                        if (array[i] > 0)
                        printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , 'e' );

                    break;
                case 102:
                        if (array[i] > 0)
                        printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , 'f' );

                    break;
                case 103:
                        if (array[i] > 0)
                        printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , 'g' );

                    break;
                case 104:
                        if (array[i] > 0)
                        printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , 'h' );

                    break;
                case 105:
                        if (array[i] > 0)
                        printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , 'i' );

                    break;
                case 106:
                        if (array[i] > 0)
                        printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , 'j' );

                    break;
                case 107:
                        if (array[i] > 0)
                        printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , 'k' );

                    break;
                case 108:
                        if (array[i] > 0)
                        printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , 'l' );

                    break;
                case 109:
                        if (array[i] > 0)
                        printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , 'm' );

                    break;
                case 110:
                        if (array[i] > 0)
                        printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , 'n' );

                    break;
                case 111:
                        if (array[i] > 0)
                        printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , 'o' );

                    break;
                case 112:
                        if (array[i] > 0)
                        printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , 'p' );

                    break;
                case 113:
                        if (array[i] > 0)
                        printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , 'q' );

                    break;
                case 114:
                        if (array[i] > 0)
                        printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , 'r' );

                    break;
                case 115:
                        if (array[i] > 0)
                        printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , 's' );

                    break;
                case 116:
                        if (array[i] > 0)
                        printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , 't' );

                    break;
                case 117:
                        if (array[i] > 0)
                        printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , 'u' );

                    break;
                case 118:
                        if (array[i] > 0)
                        printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , 'v' );

                    break;
                case 119:
                        if (array[i] > 0)
                        printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , 'w' );

                    break;
                case 120:
                        if (array[i] > 0)
                        printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , 'x' );

                    break;
                case 121:
                        if (array[i] > 0)
                        printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , 'y' );

                    break;
                case 122:
                        if (array[i] > 0)
                        printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , 'z' );

                    break;
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the line

```
            while (fscanf(fp,"%d",&filechar))
```

is wrong because

- `%d` is for reading `int`, but you passed a pointer to `char`. This will lead to access of unallocated space and it may lead to destroying of otherdata. `%c` should be used to read one character to `char`.
- `fscanf()` will return a negative number when it reached to EOF and it will treated as true when it is used as condition.

The line should be

```
            while (fscanf(fp,"%c",&filechar) == 1)
```

Secondly, your usage of `printf()` in the `switch` statement is wrong.

The first argument of `printf()` is format string and second or later arguments are data to be used according to the format string.

Instead of things like this

```
printf("There are ", array[i] , " of character: " , '!' );
```

you should write like this

```
printf("There are %d of character: %c" , array[i], '!' );
```

or like this if you want to also print newline

```
printf("There are %d of character: %c\n" , array[i], '!' );
```

`%d` is for printing an integer and `%c` is for printing a character.

Answer (score 0):

Excluding the `scanf()` and `printf()` errors as pointed out by @MikeCAT, you should also make your code more shorter and readable by replacing all the switch statement lines with this:

```
printf("There are %d of character: %c\n", array[i], i);
```

You have done the ascii conversions manually, which is not needed as the `%c` format specifier in the printf statement does exactly that.